# How do I save a correlation matrix with good resolution in R?

Tags: r, graph, resolution

```
library("PerformanceAnalytics")
chart. Correlation(my_data, histogram=TRUE, pch=19)
```

When I run the code above, R produces a correlation matrix, but the resolution is (for lack of a better word) a bit meh:

[image]

I'd like to save a high-resolution version of the matrix, and I thought I had figured out how when I came across ggsave, but as far as I can tell, ggsave can only be used to print plots, not graphs like this. When I googled the problem, everyone kept on pointing to ggsave, but if I run ggsave("myplot.png"), all I get is an empty picture.

Is it either possible to use ggsave for this, or some other solution altogether?

Answer (score 0):

I don't do too much work with base plots, however you could try something like this:

```
png("./nicePlot.png", res = 72, width = 1000, height = 1000, pointsize = 25)
PerformanceAnalytics::chart.Correlation(iris[1:2], histogram = TRUE, pch = 19)
dev.off()
```